# Flutter Web webpage freezed on index.html while pressing browser reload button

Tags: flutter, flutter-web-browser

when I click on browsers reload button my web page stucked on index.html page
while debugging I got to know that there is a javascript code i.e

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/flutter_service_worker.js');
```

it stuck on this line with the Exception

Exception while loading service worker: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:9090/wiki/') with script ('http://localhost:9090/wiki/flutter_service_worker.js?v=null'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research nd wasting time I found that there was an issue in latest Flutter SDK Update Just downgrade it to 3.3.10 and it will work.